# Restricting User access to different apps in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models in my project. Both of which reference the User class (I used the User model to gain access to methods such as authenticate and login_required)

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    Customer = models.OneToOneField(User)
    CustomerID = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex = r'\d{10}', message = 'Enter your 10 digit Mobile number')
    Phone_no = models.CharField(max_length = 10,validators = [phone_regex],blank = True)
    Customer_wallet = models.IntegerField(default = 100)


class Merchants(models.Model):
    merchant = models.OneToOneField(User)
    MerchantID = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    Storename = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
```

Currently any user(regardless of him being a merchant or a customer) has access to the entire site. What do I use to restrict a customer to /Customer url and a merchant to a /Merchant url?

```
def check_if_merchant(user):
    try:
        user.__getattribute__('merchants')
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

I tried the user_passes_test decorator to check if the user has a merchant or a customer attribute. But it seems to be automatically redirecting to /accounts/Merchants etc which hasnt been set up in urls.py.

Comment: Why don't your models inherit from `User`?

Comment: They do dont they? **  merchant = models.OneToOneField(User)**

Comment: No, they dont. To inherit you need to do  `class Foo(ClassInheritFrom):`

Comment: oh .. so i'm assuming class Foo(User.Model) would be a better way than connecting them via foriegnkeys?

Comment: Your classes are inheriting form `models.Model` you can change that to `User` and then any instance of your `Customer` or `Merchant` class will have access too all the methods and properties of the `User`class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user_passes_test` is just a simple decorator, and yes it *does* redirect to the login url as documented.

Now since `user_passes_test` calls your own test function, if you want to return a `403 Forbidden` instead you just have to raise `PermissionDenied` instead of returning `False`:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied, ObjectDoesNotExist

def check_if_merchant(user):
    try:
        user.merchants
    except (AttributeError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        return True
```

Alternatively you can first check if you have a logged in user and return False if not, to redirect non logged in users to the login page:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied, ObjectDoesNotExist

def check_if_merchant(user):
    if user.is_anonymous():
        return False
    try:
        user.merchants
    except (AttributeError, ObjectDoesNotExist):
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Thank you ! Would you recommend the same model structure? or have separate Merchant and customer models without referring the User model(if thats even possible)

Comment: @Kunkka I don't know enough about your project's requirements to recommend anything. My only recommandation at this point would be to stick to Django's nameing conventions: model class names should be singular, not plural (ie : "Merchant", not "Merchants").