# Different Users: Customer & Producer in two different Django Apps

Tags: python, django

I´m working on an Django Webpage and need some help regarding my Usermodel.

I´ll already have a Login for the both Producer & Customer that looks like this:

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class Meta:
    model = User= ['username', 'password']
    fields
```

So iff you open /producer/login or /customer/login you can login with a set name and passwort stored in the mysql DB

Now I want to change the login to a kind of global login where you have just one login page that redirects you wether you are a producer or customer.

Can anybody help me or give me a hint how i can implent this?

I red this article [Restricting User access to different apps in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291611/restricting-user-access-to-different-apps-in-django) but wasn´t sure if this is what I need.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To make a universal login you have to inherit from inbuilt `User` module, else there would be no way to check a duplicate `username`, as all username would have to be checked if it already exists in one main db_table.

Comment: I don't see why you need to subclass User to achieve this. You only need some way to distinguish the different kind of users. One way could be to test for membership of django's builtin `django.contrib.auth.Group`.

Comment: So regarding to this Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291611/restricting-user-access-to-different-apps-in-django is it right that i have to add the class Customer(models.Model) in my customer/view and the class Merchants(models.Model) in my Merchant/view and where to have to locate the function def check_if_merchant(user)?! Thanks!